# Form with value PHP submit MySQL - undefined index

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm currently trying to make so if a person presses a button, as for instance "accept application" it'll update "active" in the database from 0 to 1. This is what I have done, but apparently it will not work.

Processing part:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['acceptapplication'])){

$acceptid = $_POST['acceptid'];
$SQL = "UPDATE `users` SET `active`='1' WHERE id = $acceptid";

$result = mysql_query($SQL); }
```

And my form:

```
<form action='' name='acceptid' method='acceptapplication'>
<input value='<?php echo $charid ?>' type='submit'/>
</form>
```

In this example charid represents the number 7. I want it to do the follwing query:

UPDATE `users` SET `active`='1' WHERE id = 7

The reason I want the charid to be a value is because the value will not be the same in all occasions. Therefore it'd be good if I could manage to make this work out.

Comment: 1. method must be post based on your code.2. input must have `name` attribute.3. `mysql_*` is deprecated so use `mysqli_*` OR `PDO`

Comment: @Anant Would this be the correct way to do it in PDO? * `if(isset($_REQUEST['acceptapplication']))
{
    
    $acceptid = $_POST['acceptid'];
    $SQL = "UPDATE `users` SET `active`='1' WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($SQL);
    $stmt->execute([$acceptid]);
}`

Answer (score 0):

This `method='acceptapplication'` is wrong. You are sending as a `GET`. You also are open to SQL injections. Use parameterized queries.

Try changing it to

```
<form action='' name='acceptid' method='POST'>
```

then it will process as a `POST` request.

See this for more information:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Actually after looking over your whole form you have a few other issues.

```
<form method='POST'>
<input value='<?php echo $charid ?>' type='hidden' name='acceptid'/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Note `action=''` is not needed, without the `action` it sends the request to the same page.

The undefined index notice though is being caused by `$_POST['acceptid']` because `$_POST` is not defined/populated.

Comment: No problem. If this resolved the issue please accept the answer. Your comment with pdo usage looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should use  post method

```
 <form action='' name='acceptid' method='post'>
```

Answer (score 0):

The method of the form is wrong, you need to use POST method to pass parameters, so later on you can check the query by the $_POST['id'].